# r - Revolution R - Is modification of my original R-scripts needed?

Tags: r

I learnt from the web that Revolution R allows multi-threading and optimize running of my R-scripts.

My question is: after installation of Revolution R, if I run my R-script under Revolution R environment, will it automatically optimize running of my R-script? Or I need to modify my R-script in order to allow Revolution R to optimize running of my R-script?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your terminology may need some refinement. You may need to distinguish multi-processing from multi-threading. Revolution R does link to a multithreaded BLAS library for Windows that might otherwise not be available unless you compiled your version. Whether or not that will improve your performance is apparently somewhat dependent on what functions you use.

To use multi-processing in R, you will need set up your machine resources appropriately and then use code that distributes the parallizable tasks. Those seem to be the applications you are thinking about when you ask about modifying your scripts.  Revo-R used to have advantages here over regular R, but for the last couple of versions, the 'parallel' package has been available to all useRs.

Comment: Thank you, then in Revo R do I need to assign the CPU cores for multi-threading? If I do not assign, supposedly it should automatically use all my CPU cores for multi-threading, right?

Comment: As I said "multi-threading" is a feature of the BLAS (and automatic). But how this affects performance is dependent on the task and code. If the task would be more efficiently accomplished with multi-processing, then you need to use the proper methods.

Answer (score 2):

Revo R has multithreaded BLAS, this does not require a change in your scripts.

And GNU R, or Standard R, can of course also use multithreaded BLAS as detailed in [Appendix A.3.1 of the R Installation and Administration manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#BLAS%20%22Section%20A.3.1%20of%20the%20R%20Inst+Admin%20Manual).

Comment: Thank you, then in Revo R do I need to assign the CPU cores for multi-threading? If I do not assign, supposedly it should automatically use all my CPU cores for multi-threading, right?